# How to find the median of a random variable given its probability density function?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

Find the median of the random variable with the probability density function given below. (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

$$f(x) = 0.06\, e^{−0.06\,x}\text{ on }[0, +\infty)$$

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated as I am extremely confused on where to even start.

Comment: Hint:  the median is the value $m$ such that $P(x≤m)=\frac 12$  So, just compute $P(x≤m)$ for variable $m$ and solve for $m$

Comment: You may want to have a look a exponential distributions.

Comment: You can also search this site with keywords "median distribution random variable"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median is located where the $\text{cdf}$ reaches $1/2$.

Integrating,

$$\text{cdf}(x)=\int_0^x\text{pdf}(x) dx=\int_0^x0.06e^{-0.06x}dx=-\left.e^{-0.06x}\right|_0^x=\frac12.$$

I let you the conclude.

Comment: Is the answer then .5309?

Comment: Probably not. How do you get this value ?

Comment: Wait I did it wrong, I should have actually done ln(.5)/(-.06) and that would then give me the answer of 11.5525 which is correct

Comment: Thank you so much for your help